# How to change file parmater by input in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, vim, linux-kernel

I have a file that contain this line

SELINUX = enforce

I want to change this by given input to permissive
How i do that without demage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If [[ "$1" == "Y"]]
then
    sed -ri 's/(^.*SELINUX=)(.*$)/\1enforce/' file
else
    sed -ri 's/(^.*SELINUX=)(.*$)/\1permissive/' file
fi
```

If the first passed parameter ($1) is equal to "Y" use sed to split SELINUX line into to 2 sections. Substitute the line for the first section followed by "enforce". If the passed parameter is not "Y" substitute the line for the first section followed by "permissive".